# Messy result using reshape in R

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I dont know why, but I obtain a messy result using the reshape function, I have already tried with other answers, but I don't know why my solution is not working

```
df <- data.frame(design = c("house", "house", "car","car", "plane","plane"),
                    who = c("creator1", "creator2", "creator1", "creator2", 
                            "creator1", "creator2"),
                    how_many = c(3, 6, 1, 7, 8, 2))
```

I tried with

```
tidyr::spread(data = df, value=design , key = who)
```

The results that I have is:

```
how_many creator1 creator2
1        1      car     <NA>
2        2     <NA>    plane
3        3    house     <NA>
4        6     <NA>    house
5        7     <NA>      car
6        8    plane     <NA>
```

I want to create a dataframe with this format:

```
  Design creator1 creator2
  house  3        6
  car    1        7
  plane  8        2
```

Comment: `df %>% spread(who, how_many)`   You should have `how_many` for value, not `design`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As exemplified by @Jon Spring, and in other OS issues.

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684925/how-to-use-the-spread-function-properly-in-tidyr)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849240/tidyrspread-with-multiple-keys-and-values)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(design = c("house", "house", "car","car", 
                            "plane","plane"),
                 who = c("creator1", "creator2", "creator1", 
                         "creator2","creator1", "creator2"),
                 how_many = c(3, 6, 1, 7, 8, 2))
df
```

```
> df
  design      who how_many
1  house creator1        3
2  house creator2        6
3    car creator1        1
4    car creator2        7
5  plane creator1        8
6  plane creator2        2
```

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  tidyr::spread(who, how_many)
df2
```

```
> df2
  design creator1 creator2
1    car        1        7
2  house        3        6
3  plane        8        2
```